# How to export vaadin 8 grid to csv

Tags: java, csv, vaadin, vaadin8

Anyone knows how to export vaadin 8 grid to csv/excel? Or even how to do it in code? I found this plugin...

https://vaadin.com/directory/component/exporter

But it based in vaadin 7 framework, and it is not updated.

Thank yout

Comment: You don't export the grid, but its data, just get them and export

Comment: This one? https://vaadin.com/directory/component/excel-exporter

Comment: Thank you very much. I did with excel-exporter and works well.